# Регулярки PHP

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
$file_array=preg_replace('/\<(\d+)\>/','<img src="$1.jpg" />',  $file_array);
```

как сделать чтоб числа были без первых 0? в тексте может встречатся <080> как вместо **$1=080** получить **$1=80** ? если такой способ есть)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте переписать его где то так

```
/\<0*(\d+)\>/','<img src="$1.jpg" />
```

И включить жадный режим, если он не включен. Конструкция 0* как раз захватит ведущие нули.

Comment: знать бы еще хоть что то про "жадный" режим)) а так идея неплохая)

Comment: в жадном режиме регулярка захватывает символы по максимуму.
то есть, пусть имеем такую регулярку
0*\d+ и такую строку 00011
в жадном режиме 0* захватит все ноли. В не жадном - ни одного.
Если мне память не изменяет, то preg_replace как раз в жадном режиме и работает в данном случае.

Comment: спасибо за пояснение жадности :)

Comment: В конкретно этой ситуации, лучше сверхжадный/ревнивый